# highcharts waterfall not summing correctly

Tags: highcharts, waterfall

See jsfiddle - sum is not considering the 1st data point???

http://jsfiddle.net/Q3sPq/13/

StackOverflow is making me add more to the description because too much of this post is code...
StackOverflow is making me add more to the description because too much of this post is code...
StackOverflow is making me add more to the description because too much of this post is code...
StackOverflow is making me add more to the description because too much of this post is code...
StackOverflow is making me add more to the description because too much of this post is code...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var div = 'container';
var data = new Array(100, -5, -8, -16, -10);
var xAxis = new Array("Attempts", "Declines", "Declines", "Approved", "User", "Processor", "net");
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        type: 'waterfall',
        renderTo: div,
        width: 700,
        height: 275
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Percent '
    },

    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },

    yAxis: {
        max: 100,
        min: 25,
        title: {
            text: 'Percent'
        }
    },

    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },

    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{point.y:,.1f}%'
    },

    series: [{
        upColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3],
        data: [{
            name: xAxis[0],
            y: data[0],
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
        }, {
            name: xAxis[1],
            y: data[1]
        }, {
            name: xAxis[2],
            y: data[2]
        }, {
            name: xAxis[3],
            isIntermediateSum: true,
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
        }, {
            name: xAxis[4],
            y: data[3]
        }, {
            name: xAxis[5],
            y: data[4]
        }, {
            name: xAxis[6],
            isSum: true,
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
        }],
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            formatter: function () {
                return this.y + '%';
            },
        verticalAlign: 'top',
            style: {
                color: '#FFFFFF',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            }
        },
        pointPadding: 0
    }]
});
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug from the beta version that has been fixed in the full release. If you change the script tags to use the latest version it works fine.
http://jsfiddle.net/Q3sPq/14/

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
```

GitHub Issue:
https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1597